# ASP.Net webform/mvc3 - add link to each page of a multi-page pdf document

Tags: asp.net, pdf

My upcoming mobile web application project would include linking from a web page to each page of a multi-page pdf document.

There will be a menu on the left with all the page titles, and when the user clicks on one, it will take them to that page inside the pdf document.

Is it possible to link the individual pages this way?

The pdf will be dynamically chosen from a list of pdfs.

Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open PDF at a specific page using URLs like the following

```
http://www.example.com/my.pdf#page=3
```

You should somehow find out titles for pages, though.

Comment: While this works for desktop browsers, and #pageX works for mobile safari on iPad, after embedding the pdf in iFrame and specifying the src with the page numbers don't work. Do you have any idea how to make it work in the iFrame on the iPad?

Comment: @DebarupaDe Unfortunately, no.